# Shell script to read number between 2 text

Tags: shell

I have output file from which I want number of test Failures. File last 2 lines is as follows:

6 Tests,    0 Failures  10.071 seconds.
Test complete at Mon Jan 9 11:40:57 PST 2017Startig test at Mon Jan 9 15:07:57 PST 2017

Can anyone help me with bash script to get number of Test Failed and send email notification if there is any test failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of tests failed from the file, you can use:

```
tail -2 filename | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Emailing this number, however, would require you to setup SMTP, after which you can use the `mail` command:

```
tests_failed=$(tail -2 filename | head -1 | awk '{ print $3 }')

mail -s "${tests_failed} test cases failed" "example@example.com" <<EOF
The message body goes here
EOF
```